# How can I get an id of a left joined mySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

Like this my mySQL request is working well:

```
 <?php
       $id = 12;

        $pdo = $db->prepare("
        SELECT *,
        horse.id AS h
        FROM dog 
        LEFT JOIN cat ON dog.name=cat.name
        LEFT JOIN horse ON dog.name=horse.name
        WHERE animal = ?");
        $pdo->execute(array($id));
        $animals = $pdo->fetchAll();

        foreach ($animals as $row) {
            echo $row["h"];
        }
        ?>
```

But if I want to get the dog.id...

```
 <?php

        $id = 12;

        $pdo = $db->prepare("
        SELECT *,
        horse.id AS h
        dog.id AS d
        FROM dog 
        LEFT JOIN cat ON dog.name=cat.name
        LEFT JOIN horse ON dog.name=horse.name
        WHERE animal = ?");
        $pdo->execute(array($id));
        $animals = $pdo->fetchAll();

        foreach ($animals as $row) {
            echo $row["h"];
            echo $row["d"];
        }
        ?>
```

...there is an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'dog.id AS d FROM dog LEFT JOIN cat ON
>   dog.name=cat.name' at line 3 in /myproject.php:31 Stack trace: #0
>   /myproject.php(31): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /myproject.php on line 31

Comment: `$pdo->execute(array($id));` remove the array inside execute()

Comment: `*, horse.id AS h dog.id AS d` missing a comma after `h` there.

Comment: Okay, in that case see the answer below and/or @Qirel's comment.

Comment: @chris85 Yes, thank you, that was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data and your error message, you missed one comma in your query after `horse.id AS h` it should be

```
SELECT *,
 horse.id AS h,
 dog.id AS d
FROM dog 
LEFT JOIN cat ON dog.name=cat.name
LEFT JOIN horse ON dog.name=horse.name
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solves the problem, but strangely now I get another error message: "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'animal' in where clause is ambiguous in (...)"

Comment: Ah, I think I solved this. I need then to write: WHER dog.animal = ?. Then everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma:

```
    SELECT *,
    horse.id AS h  -- HERE
    dog.id AS d
```

Should be:

```
    SELECT *,
    horse.id AS h,
    dog.id AS d
```